# PHP how to convert or remove special charatcter from string?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to convert any special charater to it's original value and i am trying with this function but it's not working. This is my code.

```
  $text = "Tuscaloosa County â€“ Hunting and Timber Invest";

  echo $html = mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "original value"? What is the actual result and what result are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that's what you want but try it

`$text = "Tuscaloosa County â€“ Hunting and Timber Invest";
      echo $html =mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: it's not converting this â€“

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Clean function**

```
function clean($string) {
       $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.

       return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
    }
     $text = "Tuscaloosa County â€“ Hunting and Timber Invest";

      echo $html = clean($text);
```

Comment: there can be more special character because content is dynamic

Comment: I think this **clean** function replace or remove all the special characters into string

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Try to use next:

```
 $text = "Tuscaloosa County â€“ Hunting and Timber Invest";
$html_1 = utf8_encode($text);
$html_2 = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $text);
$html_2 = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

or

```
 $text = "Tuscaloosa County â€“ Hunting and Timber Invest";
$html_1 = utf8_decode($text);
$html_2 = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $text);
$html_2 = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```

**2**. And this way:

```
$html= mb_convert_encode($text,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8');
```

Comment: no there can be more special characters because conetnt is dynmaic

Comment: @user3714488 do you know original coding of your sp chars?

Comment: @user3714488, I've studied your case and changed the answer, check it.

Comment: Tuscaloosa County Ã¢â¬â Hunting and Timber Invest  It's returning this

Comment: @user3714488, I can't figure out what coding need for you at the end. See the other way

Answer (score 0):

```
$new2old = array(
            'á' => 'Ã¡','À' => 'Ã€',
            'ä' => 'Ã¤','Ä' => 'Ã„','ã' => 'Ã£','å' => 'Ã¥','Å' => 'Ã…','æ' => 'Ã¦','Æ' => 'Ã†',
            'ç' => 'Ã§','Ç' => 'Ã‡','é' => 'Ã©','É' => 'Ã‰','è' => 'Ã¨','È' => 'Ãˆ','ê' => 'Ãª',
            'Ê' => 'ÃŠ','ë' => 'Ã«','Ë' => 'Ã‹','í' => 'Ã-­­','Í' => 'Ã','ì' => 'Ã¬','Ì' => 'ÃŒ',
            'î' => 'Ã®','Î' => 'ÃŽ','ï' => 'Ã¯','Ï' => 'Ã','ñ' => 'Ã±','Ñ' => 'Ã‘','ó' => 'Ã³',
            'Ó' => 'Ã“','ò' => 'Ã²','Ò' => 'Ã’','ô' => 'Ã´','Ô' => 'Ã”','ö' => 'Ã¶','Ö' => 'Ã–',
            'õ' => 'Ãµ','Õ' => 'Ã•','ø' => 'Ã¸','Ø' => 'Ã˜','œ' => 'Å“','Œ' => 'Å’','ß' => 'ÃŸ',
            'ú' => 'Ãº','Ú' => 'Ãš','ù' => 'Ã¹','Ù' => 'Ã™','û' => 'Ã»','Û' => 'Ã›','ü' => 'Ã¼',
            'Ü' => 'Ãœ','€' => 'â‚¬','’' => 'â€™','‚' => 'â€š','ƒ' => 'Æ’','„' => 'â€ž','…' => 'â€¦',
            '‡' => 'â€¡','ˆ' => 'Ë†','‰' => 'â€°','Š' => 'Å ','‹' => 'â€¹','Ž' => 'Å½','‘' => 'â€˜',
            '“' => 'â€œ','•' => 'â€¢','–' => 'â€“','—' => 'â€”','˜' => 'Ëœ','™' => 'â„¢','š' => 'Å¡',
            '›' => 'â€º','ž' => 'Å¾','Ÿ' => 'Å¸','¡' => 'Â¡','¢' => 'Â¢','£' => 'Â£','¤' => 'Â¤','¥' => 'Â¥',
            '¦' => 'Â¦','§' => 'Â§','¨' => 'Â¨','©' => 'Â©','ª' => 'Âª','«' => 'Â«','¬' => 'Â¬','®' => 'Â®',
            '¯' => 'Â¯','°' => 'Â°','±' => 'Â±','²' => 'Â²','³' => 'Â³','´' => 'Â´','µ' => 'Âµ','¶' => 'Â¶',
            '·' => 'Â·','¸' => 'Â¸','¹' => 'Â¹','º' => 'Âº','»' => 'Â»','¼' => 'Â¼','½' => 'Â½','¾' => 'Â¾',
            '¿' => 'Â¿','à' => 'Ã ','†' => 'â€ ','”' => 'â€','Á' => 'Ã','â' => 'Ã¢','Â' => 'Ã‚','Ã' => 'Ãƒ',
         );

         foreach( $new2old as $key => $value ) {
                $new[] = $key;
                $old[] = $value;
         }
  $text = "Tuscaloosa County â€“ Hunting and Timber Invest";
  echo $html =$string_new = str_replace( $old, $new, $text );
```

`